# Combining Agents with Tasks in F#

Tags: concurrency, f#

I have the following code in F# which is think is sufficiently concurrent to utilize the 4 cores of my machine. Yet cpu usage is limited to one core.

```
    member x.Solve problemDef =
        use flag = new ManualResetEventSlim(false)
        let foundSoFar = MSet<'T>()
        let workPile = MailboxProcessor<seq<'T>>.Start(fun inbox ->
            let remaining = ref 0
            let rec loop() = async {
                let! data = inbox.Receive()
                let data = data |> Seq.filter (not << foundSoFar.Contains) |> Array.ofSeq
                foundSoFar.UnionWith data
                let jobs = ref -1
                for chunk in data |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.chunked 5000 do
                    Async.Start <| async {
                        Seq.collect problemDef.generators chunk
                        |> Array.ofSeq
                        |> inbox.Post
                    }
                    incr jobs
                remaining := !remaining + !jobs
                if (!remaining = 0 && !jobs = -1) then
                    flag.Set() |> ignore
                else 
                    return! loop()
            }
            loop()
        )
        workPile.Post problemDef.initData
        flag.Wait() |> ignore
        foundSoFar :> seq<_>
```

I use the MailboxProcessor as a workpile from where I get chunks of elements, filter them through a HashSet and create tasks with the new elements whose results are inserted in the workpile. This is repeated until no new elements are produced. The aim of this code is to asynchronously insert the chunks in the workpile, thus the use of tasks. My problem is that there is no parallelism.

Edit: thanks to @jon-harrop I solved the concurrency problem which was due to the lazy nature of seq, and rewrought the code following the suggestions. Is there any way to get rid of the ManualResetEvent without using a discriminated union as the message type of the agent(to support the asking message)?

Answer (score 2):

Without a complete example, I found it quite difficult to understand what your code does (perhaps because it combines quite a few different concurrent programming primitives, which makes it a bit hard to follow).

Anyway, the body of `MailboxProcessor` is executed only once (if you want to get concurrency using plain agents, you need to start multiple agents). In the body of the agent, you start a task that runs `problemDef.generators` for each `chunk`.

This means that `problemDef.generators` should run in parallel. However the code that calls `foundSoFar.Contains` and `foundSoFar.UnionWith` as well as `Seq.distinct` is always run sequentially.

So, if `problemDef.generators` is a simple and efficient function, the overhead with tracking `foundSoFar` (which is done sequentially) is probably larger than what you get by parallelization.

I'm not familiar with `MSet<'T>`, but if it is (or if you replaced it with) a thread safe mutable set, then you should be able to run some of the unioning right in the `Task.StartNew` (in parallel with other unioning).

PS: As I said, it is difficult to tell without running the code, so my thinking may be completely wrong!

Comment: The system I try to create consists of an **Agent** which keeps track of the found elements(in **foundSoFar** - this is a plain **HashSet** aliased as **MSet**) and some mappers that apply the **generators** to each chunk and send the result back to the **workPile**. For the mappers, instead of using more **Agents** and the related overhead, I use the tasks created by **Task.Factory.StartNew**. I cut the data into chunks of 5000 elements, and I want parallelism between the mapping of each chunk. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing high-level concurrency primitives (tasks and agents) with `ManualResetEventSlim`  which is very bad. Can you use `PostAndReply` instead?

You're using `Seq` to do "work" in the spawned task which is lazy so it won't actually do anything until after it is posted back. Can you force evaluation inside the task with something like `Array.ofSeq`?

The way you are using `Task` is anomalous. Might be more idiomatic to switch to `Async.Start`.

Without a complete solution I cannot validate any of my guesses...

> think is sufficiently concurrent to utilize the 4 cores

Your mental model of multicore parallelism might be quite off the mark.